# Making an implicit data value explicit in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm working with a bit of a bizarre data format, from which there's a bit of information I'd like to extract. I've done some of this work in python, but I was curious if it's crazy to attempt some of this in **R**.

---

The format is like this: Three columns:

- Column 1 is a timestamp
- Column 2 is an observation type (a factor)
- Column 3 is a group indicator

The oddness of this format comes from certain logical constraints that come from the ordering.

- Some of the observations are start / stop pairs (no nesting, but other observations could be inside the start-stop pairs)
- The timestamps are generally monotonically increasing -- except that a fourth group indicator is implicitly provided by the ordering of monotonically increasing chunks.

  In case that's not clear, consider the following sequence of timestamps:

  ```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 
        0    |    1  |    2
  ```

  This is 3 chunks, where the first chunk all have the second group indicator of 0, the second group have indicator 1, etc.

---

Everything becomes a bit easier if I can make that 4th indicator explicit; This is easy enough in python, but I was hoping to keep this all in **R**.

A straight loop over the data would be easy enough, but I figure there *may* be a faster more **R**ish --- vector-- way to do this.

Comment: It could just be me, but I haven't the foggiest idea what you're trying to describe at all. You may need to provide a small example data set along with this "4th indicator" already computed, because as it is I have no idea what it should be at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tt <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
grp <- cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(tt) < 0))
```

which gives:

```
> grp
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm terribly unused to thinking in vectors, but I knew there had to be a better way to do this than a loop!